# How can I restore my display settings in Windows 7 after I put my computer to sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, hibernate

My computer has Windows 7 (RTM) as an OS and I'm using two monitors.

The power saving settings put the computer to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. When the computer wakes up, it always uses only one monitor instead of all two. Always the second one, not the monitor I use as a primary display. So the taks bar, start menu and all icons are moved to this second monitor. The other monitor is just black.

I can restore my preferred dual monitor setting by displaying Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution and changing the setting of "Multiple Displays" to "Extend these displays". 
However, I don't want to do this every time my computer wakes up.

The computer worked fine with the two displays with Windows XP.

Does anyone know if this is a feature or a bug and how to wake up my Windows 7 with both displays running.

Comment: I had this with mine too and gave up in the end.  It turned out that my graphics card (ATI 800XT) wasn't compatible with Windows 7.  What graphics card is it exactly and do you have up to date drivers installed for it?

Comment: I have a GeForce 7300 GT. The driver was pretty new but not the latest version. I will try to update and check if this make a difference.

Comment: I updated the drivers, but got the same error today.

Comment: Just an update: I didn't find a solution, so I just turned off the set to sleep command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler for this. Waking from sleep is Event ID 1. So for parameters of your Task use:

- Trigger: "On An Event"
- Log: System
- Source: Power-Troubleshooter
- Event ID: 1

now for the task to run, you can use [Multires](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/multires.shtm). Point task scheduler to the location of `multires.exe` and use the command-line parameters to reset the display to the same settings it should already be using. Something like this should work:

```
C:\multires.exe /1:1680,1050,32,75 /2:1680,1050,32,75
```

This would set both monitors to 1680x1050 resolution @ 32-bit color and 75hz refresh rate. It should trigger the other monitor just as if you changed these settings in the display settings.